# why in the below code i'm not able to print the return statement with the dot notation in javascript

Tags: javascript, notation

I'm learning javascript and i came across this problem in which i have a function that takes an object and a property and i have to check with the help of `object.hasOwnProperty` function that the object passed to the function has the property or not and if it has the property than return the value of it else return "Not Found".

This is the function i created:

```
function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)){
    return obj.checkProp;  
  }else{
    return "Not Found";
  }  
}
```

input for the function:

```
checkObj({gift: "pony", pet: "kitten", bed: "sleigh"}, "gift")
```

so what i found that after hours of trying and finally watching the solution video is that the bracket notation would do the job
solution code

```
function checkObj(obj, checkProp) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp)){
    return obj[checkProp];  
  }else{
    return "Not Found";
  }  
}
```

So can anyone please shed some light on why dot notation could not achieve the task?

Comment: The dot `.` is a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), you're explicitly trying to access a property called `checkProp` which doesn't exist.

Comment: As I just changed an complet allcaps sentence to common spelling, please be advised that allcaps is considered yelling on the internet if not used to emphasize single words, and pleas note that people do not like getting yelled at. You might want to apply common internet netiquette when asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, the dot operator is used to access properties of objects. It's takes a object as first parameter, and a property name as second operator. Note: it takes *property name* as second parameter - no further substitution or code execution is done on the second parameter.

If you use `obj.checkProperty`, you're accessing the property named `checkProperty` of the object stored in `obj`. This object does not have a property with that name in your example, so this will fail.

What you *want* to achieve is to call the property with the *name stored in the variable `checkProperty`*. This has to be done using the bracket notation, since here, further code execution is done - note the difference between `obj["checkProperty"]` (which is euqal to `obj.checkProperty`) and `obj[checkProperty]`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work with the dot notation because`obj.checkProp` tries to read the property named *checkProp* from obj.